# Override ids generation (R file) in gradle android plugin (use public.xml)

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle

I want to override ids generation in new (2.2.2) Android Gradle Plugin in order to make constant ids. Ids are located in public.xml file. This is mandatory if I want to create a separate app that extends Theme of my main application. (standalone theme)

Android Gradle Plugin 1.2.3 <= - generates ids for resources in R files, using public.xml file

Android Gradle Plugin >= 1.3.0 ignores public.xml file. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182046

Is there any way to hack it?

Comment: If you ask me overriding the ID generation is a bad idea. I would avoid doing this, and find another way to maintain your theme.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai You tell me that it is bad, but you don't suggest another way

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish. If you want the same theme on another app, then you just set both apps up to use the same theme. You could probably copy and paste you style files. I don't understand why you would want to override the generated files in the first place.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai Example: I have main app. And I want to create a lot of stanalone themes for this app. Each theme is stanadalone apk

Comment: I'm not quite sure  why you would want to d that when you have the ability to create multiple themes within the app itself. Creating a standalone APK servers no purpose.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai What if I want to 3-parties developers to create their own themes?

Comment: Then I'd have the developers submit the code to me and I would add the theme via an update. Or, you could look at using a content provider and allowing 3rd parties the ability to access and modify data in a way that would all them to create their own themes.  Creating a second APK means you would have to have 2 apps running to run a single app. Not a good idea.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai it's good idea. Take a look at these apps - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.stellio.player.skin.redline

Comment: 3rd parties aren't developing those. They are done by the team that released the app itself, which means they have access to their own API, which would allow something like this to adjust their own application.

Comment: Which could honestly just be an APK with some images that are hooked into the application. Allowing 3rd parties to do this with your own app could be dangerous.